# Kaminari : undefined method total_pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I have a problem on Kaminari with Rails 4.

Here it is my renters_controller.rb

```
def search
  @location = params[:search]
  @distance = params[:km]
  @renters = Renter.near(@location, 30000).order("distance")
  @renters = @renters.page(params[:page])

  if @renters.empty?
    @renters = Renter.all
    search_map(@renters)
  else
    search_map(@renters)
  end
end
```

and my view search.html.haml.

```
.row
  = paginate @renters
```

and my error message

```
Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=" for ::1 at 2016-03-17 09:37:59 +0100
Processing by RentersController#search as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>""}
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "renters" WHERE (false) LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
Renter Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "renters".* FROM "renters"
Rendered renters/search.html.haml within layouts/application (8.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for #<Renter::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd4d36bdc30>):
1: .row
2:   = paginate @renters
app/views/renters/search.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_renters_search_html_haml__3667517883215455359_70276042599600'
```

In the controller, it works if I write

```
@renters = Renter.page(params[:page])
```

Any idea ?

Comment: replace this line `@renters = Renter.near(@location, 30000).order("distance").page(params[:page])` with `@renters = Renter.near(@location, 30000).order("distance")` and put following at the end of the method `@renters = @renters.page(params[:page])`

Comment: Thank you Amit, but I still have the same error.

Comment: can you please update question with my piece of code?

Comment: please check my answer and try to run i hope it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, I hope this will work.

```
def search
  @location = params[:search]
  @distance = params[:km]
  @renters = Renter.near(@location, 30000).order("distance")

  if @renters.empty?
    @renters = Renter.all
    search_map(@renters)
  else
    search_map(@renters)
  end
  @renters = @renters.page(params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Can you explain me why if you have 5 minutes?

Comment: Ya sure, its raising an error because when this `@renters = Renter.near(@location, 30000).order("distance")` returns blank array your code executes `@renters = Renter.all` and the  `@renters` contains all records which is an active record collection, but as per kaminari doc your collection should have `.page(params[:page])` before calling `= paginate @renters`. Their `.page` converts active record collection to kaminari.